# Multiple choose file button

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What I want to achieve is have another choose file button to upload another file only after a file is attached to the first one.

I am doing the following to render my button:

```
<FormControl
   type="file"
   accept=".jpg"
   onChange={this.onImageUpload}
/>
```

What I tried is to have an array of any with one null value, to begin with. When `onImageUpload` is evoked I push the values on the file into the array. Now I have 2 elements in the array, null and the file. I try to iterate over the length of the array and render that many choose a file to upload buttons. The problem is I lose the file names next to the button on doing this. How can I add a new button without losing the filename on the previous one?

[image: After one file upload]

[image: Before one file upload]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is have an array state declared in the constructor with a single `FormControl` at index 0 like this,

```
constructor(props) {
   this.state = {
      FormControls: [
       <FormControl
         type="file"
         accept=".jpg"
         onChange={this.onImageUpload}
       />
     ]
   }
}
```

and then insert another to the array whenever an image is uploaded (onChange is triggered) like this,

```
onImageUpload() {
   let formArray = this.state.FormControls;
   formArray.push(<FormControl
         type="file"
         accept=".jpg"
         onChange={this.onImageUpload}
       />
   );
   this.setState({FormControls: formArray})
}
```

and finally, have the top parent include all the input (FormControl) like this,

```
<ParentView>{this.state.FormControls}</ParentView>
```

Also, don't forget to add a new and unique `ref` to the FormControl while adding it to the array.

Comment: Works great, only problem is when I change an uploaded file then a new button is added. So if I keep changing the image on my first button, still new buttons are generated. how should I fix that?

Comment: You need to keep track of that FormControl (using ref, for example) as to check if it has previously selected a file or not. If it has, don't add another button to the list inside `onImageUpload`